# Overstay in the Philippines

Tags: overstaying, philippines

Can a US citizen apply for a Philippines passport to get out of the Philippines even if overstaying? Or is there a chance, if I apply for a Philippines passport, that the penalty will be lower?

Comment: If you are not a Philippines citizen and apply for a Philippines passport, the fine for your overstay will be the least of your worries.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question coherently, since passports are a form of ID, not something used to give permission to stay in a country.  Maybe you meant to ask a question about Visas?

Answer (score 18):

If you are a Philippines citizen, you are legally entitled to stay in the Philippines as long as you like and cannot "overstay", regardless of what passport you used to enter.

If you are already a citizen with documentation to prove it, you're fine and should definitely get a Philippines passport.

If you are not officially recognized as a citizen but have the right to be recognized as one through parents/birth/etc, you should also be fine, but you need to sort out your paperwork ASAP.

However, if you are *not* a citizen and need to apply as a US citizen who wants to naturalize on their own merits, overstaying is almost certainly going to be a blocker.

Comment: Not knowing the Ops situation but some information on the [Philipines Nationality Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippine_nationality_law) may help. In summary: Any person born to at least one Filipino parent receives Philippine citizenship at birth. "Foreign nationals may naturalize as Philippine citizens after meeting a minimum residence requirement (usually 10 years), acquiring real estate, demonstrating proficiency in either English or Spanish as well as a Philippine language, and fulfilling a good character requirement. "